# How to fake delegates with FakeItEasy

Tags: fakeiteasy

When i try to fake a delegate-type, i get System.InvalidCastException

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestDelegateFake()
{
    var func = A.Fake<Func<long, object>>();

    A.CallTo(() => func(A<long>.Ignored))
        .Returns(new {});

    func(123);
}
```

How du i fake delegates?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you have to specify the Invoke-method explicitly:

```
A.CallTo(() => func.Invoke(A<long>.Ignored)).Returns(new {});
```

Comment: I have fixed this in the latest version https://nuget.org/packages/FakeItEasy/1.7.4582.63

Comment: The posted fix worked without the call to Invoke. I think that is more intuitive - thx.